# Full postback triggered by CheckBox inside GridView inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a GridView inside of a UpdatePanel. In a template field is a CheckBox I use for marking items. Functionally, this works fine, but the CheckBox always triggers a full page postback instead of a partial postback. How do I get the CheckBox to trigger a partial postback?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_test" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_View_CheckAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="cb_View_CheckAll_CheckedChanged"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `trigger` and `scriptmanager`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="script" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="cb_View_CheckAll" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: because CheckBox is placed inside the grid-view, so compiler can not find this child control drectly and fire compiler error

'A control with ID 'cb_View_CheckAll' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.'

Answer (score 0):

In your ScriptManager add `EnablePartialRendering="true"`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" > </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Or in Code Behind try to add AsyncPostbackTrigger

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(gv_test);
```

Comment: where i should i add AsyncPostbackTrigger, i mean in which event?

Comment: @UsfNoor in your Pageload , but not in `!Ispostback`